# How to save div elements into a array?

Tags: javascript

I want to save my div child elements text content into an array using Javascript. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

```
<div id="messages">
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
</div>
```

**Expected output:**

```
var messages = ["test", "test", "test", "test"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what is being asked here. I assume you want the contents to be a part of an array. The following should do the trick:

```js
var messages = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#messages div')).map(v => v.innerText)
```

```html
<div id="messages">
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
</div>
```

Note: I corrected your HTML, `<div>test/div>` is a typo and should be `<div>test</div>`

Comment: your answer is accurate, but you need to swap .querySelector for .querySelectorAll as the former wouldn't result in multiple elements being added to an array and would produce undesired results.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var messages = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelector("#messages").children, (e => e.textContent))

console.log(messages);
```

```html
<div id="messages">
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
</div>
```